# How to use TThread.Synchronize() to retrieve the text of a TEdit control?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

How can I use `TThread.Synchronize()` to retrieve the text of a `TEdit` control. Should I assign the `TEdit` text to a global variable or something?

Comment: You really don't want your threads to know about your UI internals. You need to isolate these different aspects of your program.

Comment: @David Heffernan I am writing a very small program, and this is the only UI control access I need to do.

Comment: I'd create an interface that allows the thread to request the value. The implementation of that interface could be to Synchronize to the main thread to get the value. I certainly would not be using global variables. However, it sounds like you don't care about doing things in an elegant way so I'm not really sure what to recommend.

Comment: @David Heffernan My program is literally very small (has only one Form), so I guess in this case there is no harm in placing the `TEdit` text in a global variable :)

Comment: Go ahead if you are happy with that. If that feels better to you than an interface or an anonymous method, knock yourself out.

Comment: Can't you receive the value before the thread starts? Perhaps you could pass the edit text to the TThread's constructor

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound The thread needs to always check the value and not just one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, declare a method in your form that retrieves the text.
This method can be called both from the main thread and a worker thread:

```
Type
  TMyGetTextProc = procedure(var s: String) of object;

procedure TForm1.GetMyText(var myText: String);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure 
    begin
      myText := ATedit.Text;
    end
  );
end;
```

---

Secondly, when you create the thread, pass the (callback) method in the create method and use it to get the text in a thread safe manner:

```
Type
  TMyThread = Class(TThread)
  private
    FGetTextCallback: TMyGetTextProc;
  public
    constructor Create(aGetTextProc: TMyGetTextProc);
  ...
  end;
```

Note, you can also do the syncronization from your thread directly if you prefer that. The point is that you pass a callback method to the worker thread.

As David mention in comments, always separate the UI part from worker threads (and for all business logic as well). Even in small programs, since they tend to grow over time, and suddenly you find yourself (or a co-worker) in a bad position with lots of code that is hard to maintain or understand.